# single source of truth for data with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular using restangular to hit an api. here is an example of a model

```
ReservationModel.factory('ReservationRestangular', function (Restangular) {
        var baseURL = '';
        return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
            RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl(baseURL);
        });
    }).service('ReservationService', ['ReservationRestangular', function(ReservationRestangular) {

            this.get = function(id) {
        return ReservationRestangular.one('reservations', id).get().then(function(response) {
            return response;
        });
    };

    this.all = function() {
        return ReservationRestangular.all('reservations').getList().then(function(response) {
            return response;
        });
    };
    }]);
```

currently each controller that needs a list of reservations calls ReservationService.all which hits the server and then if they need a specific reservation they call ReservationService.get and that hits the server.  if they move to a different part of the app were the controller needs reservations it does this again.

What I would like is for the server to only be hit the first time say all is called and store the response in a variable in ReservationService that can be checked next time and returned immediately instead of hitting the server again.

if a reservation is created or edited it can then call all again to get an updated list

if an individual reservation is requested it should check the stored list of reservations first and return the reservation from that list if found instead of hitting the server.

is this the correct way to do things?

is the best place for this the ReservationService?  its a singleton so should only be created once 'per session' (might not be the right terminology) and shared between all the modules and controllers ?

Comment: "is this the correct way to do things?" maybe.if you stick to UPDATE=>REFRESH the list it should be fine,just that the user wont get db updates in realtime,if another user updates the list.